# Determine whether the following fields are Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Determine whether the following fields are Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$.

(a) $\mathbb{Q}(\omega )$, where $\omega  = exp(2\pi  i/3)$.

(b) $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$

(c) $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7})$

(a) Clearly $\omega $ is the root of $x^2+x+1$, so if $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega )$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\omega )$ then $\sigma$ is also the root of $x^2+x+1$, but the only root of this is $\omega $, then $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega ):\mathbb{Q}]=2$ and $|Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\omega )/\mathbb{Q})|=1$, where $\mathbb{Q}(\omega )$ is not galois on $\mathbb{Q}$

(b) $\sqrt[4]{2}$ is the root of $x^4-2$ and $x^4-2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ where $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$, in addition if $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ then $\sigma$ also is the root of $x^4-2$, and as $x^4-2=(x-\sqrt[4]{2})(x+\sqrt[4]{2})(x-i\sqrt[4]{2})(x+i\sqrt[4]{2})$ then $\sigma=\sqrt[4]{2}, -\sqrt[4]{2}, i\sqrt[4]{2}, -i\sqrt[4]{2}$ and thus $|Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q})|=4$, we conclude that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ is Galois copper $\mathbb{Q}$.

(c) I do not know how to do this, someone could explain to me how to find an irreducible polynomial that has as roots $\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{7}$, I know that for $\sqrt{5}$ is $x^2-5$ and for $\sqrt{7}$ is $x^2-7$ but I do not know how to make this case. Thank you very much.

Comment: Look up the definition of an automorphism. Your understanding of what is an automorphism is way off.

Comment: @TrevorGunn 
Why is it far? Where do I have errors?

Comment: Everywhere. The whole thing is wrong and it's because you don't know what an automorphism is.

Comment: @TrevorGunn 
Tell me where I specifically have errors, how would you do the exercise then?

Comment: You need to first understand what an automorphism is. You seem to understand that an extension $E/F$ is Galois iff $|\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)| = [E : F]$ so that's a start. But if you don't know what an automorphism is you can't compute $|\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)|$ and therefore you can't see than an extension is Galois. For instance, the automorphism group of $\mathbf{C}/\mathbf{R}$ is the two automprhisms $f(a + bi) = a + bi$ and $g(a + bi) = a - bi$.

Comment: Comments: A) $x^2+x+1$ has real coefficients, so if $\omega$ is a zero, so is $\overline{\omega}$. B) The question is whether $\pm i\root4\of2$ are in $\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of2)$ (see Lord Shark's answer). C) $(x^2-5)(x^2-7)$ has those zeros, but is not irreducible. Does that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(a) every quadratic extension is Galois (except maybe in characteristic two).

(b) $\sqrt[4]2\in \Bbb R $ but its conjugate $i\sqrt[4]2\notin \Bbb R $.

(c) A compositum of Galois extensions is Galois.

Comment: (a) What is a quadratic extension? (b) and how does it help me to solve the problem? (c) how are Galois extensions composed? Please be more explicit, Thank you.

Comment: @user425181 (a) a degree two extension, (b) for $\Bbb Q(\alpha)/\Bbb Q$ to be Galois, all conjugates of $\alpha$ must lie in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, (c) $K(\alpha,\beta)/K$ is a compositum of $K(\alpha)/K$ and $K(\beta)/K$.

Comment: It should be $\mathbf Q$ in (b).